# jQuery Plugin - calling a public function / method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an image slider plugin that I've made that I want to extend some of the functionality of. I would like to make it so you can call the next method by calling the following like the jQuery UI does:

`$("#elemID").imageSlider("next");`

I'm kind of at a loss on how to get this done. Here is what I have so far with some of the guts missing for space.

```
(function($) {  
$.fn.imageSlider = function (options) {
    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.imageSlider.defaults, options),
        obj = $(this),                          // Set it here so we only look for it once
        objID = obj.attr('id'),
        sliderName = objID + '_slider',
        total = 0,
        counterID = objID + '_ct';

    // Private Methods
    var initialize = function () {          
        if (options.jsonObject === null) {
            processAjax();
        } else {
            process(options.jsonObject);
        }

        return obj;
    }

    // Executes an AJAX call
    var processAjax = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: options.jsonScript,
            type: 'GET',
            data: options.ajaxData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                process(data);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                if (options.onComplete !== $.noop) {
                    options.onComplete.call();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var process = function (data) {
        // Generates the HTML
    }

    var changeImage = function (me, target, ops) {
        //rotate the image
    }

    $.fn.imageSlider.next = function (elemID) {
        // Currently how I call next on the slider
    }

    return initialize();
}


$.fn.imageSlider.defaults = {
    // options go here
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this ([see docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods)) is to create an object called `methods` with stores each of your methods by name, and the actual extension looks up the the method to call by name and runs it.  Like...

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { // THIS },
    process : function( ) { // IS   },
    changeImage : function( ) { // GOOD },
    next : function( content ) { // !!! }
  };

  $.fn.imageSlider = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.imageSlider' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks! I must have looked at that a million times and just never realized it.